# How do i redirect subdirectory to URL parameter in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I want to redirect a subdirectory to a URL-parameter in the .htaccess

Like this:

domain.com/search/123 -> domain.com/searchresult?search=123

How is this possible in .htaccess

Comment: How is `/searchresult?search=123` currently handled? That doesn't look like a valid end-point and would likely require further rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)?

There even is an "Rewrite query string" example:

> This solution shows the reverse of the previous ones, copying path
> components (perhaps PATH_INFO) from the URL into the query string.
>
> ```
> # The desired URL might be /products/kitchen-sink, and the script expects
> # /path?products=kitchen-sink.
> RewriteRule "^/?path/([^/]+)/([^/]+)" "/path?$1=$2" [PT]
> ```
>
> -- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#rewrite-query

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ searchresult?$1=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This did not work - i tried in but it did not redirect